# In Julia, why can "if false" statements in local scope modify function definitions?

Tags: function, julia, scoping

In Julia 1.4.1, if I define a function in a global scope, modifications after "if false" statements do not affect it, as expected:

```
test()=0
if false
  test()=1
end

println(test())
```

This prints "0", as it should. However, when I enclose this code within a local scope, the behavior changes:

```
function main()
  test()=0
  if false
    test()=1
  end

  println(test())
end

main()
```

This now prints "1" which I did not expect. If I change "test" to be an array or a float I observe no modification as expected, i.e. the problem does not occur. Why does Julia behave this way for functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use anonymous functions in cases like this:

```
function main()
  test = () -> 0
  if false
    test = () -> 1
  end

  println(test())
end

julia> main()
0
```

As for the why, this gets to the core of [what it means to define and redefine a particular method of a function](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/15602#issuecomment-226518246).

Comment: To be clear: I think it's a bug that this doesn't at least warn you about it.